# Z-index not behaving as expected with absolute positioning inside a fixed position element

Tags: css, css-position, z-index

I've got a situation where I've got 2 or more fixed position elements on a page displaying stacked one on top of the other (that is, the top of the second one is abutting the bottom of the first one - no z-index stacking of those elements). Inside the first fixed position element, there's an absolutely positioned element which is taller than its fixed parent, so it extends beyond the bottom of that fixed parent.

The trouble is that the next fixed position element gets displayed on top of the absolutely positioned element. I've got a higher z-index value set on the absolutely positioned element than on the fixed positioned elements, but it is ignored completely.

To help clarify the issue, I put together this example:

**HTML**

```
<div class="fixed first">
    <p>This is a fixed element</p>
    <p class="abs">
        I should be displayed above both fixed position elements
    </p>
</div>
<div class="fixed second">
    <p>This is a fixed element</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.fixed {
    font-size: 16px;
    background: #eee;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    position: fixed;
    height: 3em;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}

.abs {
    position: absolute;
    background: #acc;
    height: 6em;
    top: 0;
    left: 25%;
    width: 50%;
    z-index: 2;
}

.second {
    top: 3.0625em;
}
```

Here's the working example on JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/GS4E4/8/

I'm kind of stumped by this. Does anyone have an explanation as to why this is happening, and a way to work around it?

Comment: [this has a good explanation on how z-index works](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/), as you will see all elements on the same level which have a z-index will take precedence over the child layer z-index's.  With this in mind your above fiddle is working as expected

Comment: Of course! I forgot that each positioned element creates its own stacking context. Because each fixed position element in the example has the same z-index value, the source order comes into play. Thanks for the reminder, Pete.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Pete's comment alludes to, it all comes down to stacking contexts. In this case, both `.fixed` elements create their own stacking contexts by virtue of being `position: fixed;`. The child of the first `.fixed` element creates a stacking context *nested* within its parent. Because it's nested inside an existing stacking context, it can never break out and stack any higher; its z-index is relative to its parent now.

The spec is actually somewhat helpful with the particulars: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index. You can see via the numbered list that child stacking contexts are painted dead last.

So in your case, your `.fixed.first` element would need to have a z-index of 2 for its child to stack atop `.fixed.second`.

Comment: Thanks Adam! I had totally forgotten about the individual stacking contexts of positioned parent elements. With that in mind, I've updated the fiddle with a fix that reflects this: http://jsfiddle.net/GS4E4/13/

Answer (score 1):

Move .abs outside of both divs.

```
<div class="fixed first">
    <p>This is a fixed element</p>   
</div>
<div class="fixed second">
    <p>This is a fixed element</p>
</div>
<p class="abs">
        I should be displayed above both fixed position elements
    </p>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/GS4E4/9/
The way you have it now .abs is positioned relative to .first so it will sit above .first but not above .second, your fiddle is interpreting correctly.

Comment: Thanks Irwin. I do realize that's an option, and in this simple example, it's an easy thing to do. In the context of the app which I'm working on where this issue is showing up, however, that's a more difficult option, as the layout is a lot more complex. I will consider this if there aren't any other reasonable solutions.