# Moving div on top of header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using [datatables](http://www.datatables.net/) to make a simple grid and it comes with a search button which can be used to filter specfic search query. At the moment i have the search bar toggoling by click search button. i am trying to move the search bar over the header as displayed in the picture below. This is the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3rR6J/45/)

[image]

I tried messing around with its classs id by changing the padding , position but no luck

```
.ui-input-text.ui-body-inherit.ui-corner-all.ui-shadow-inset{

//Tried everything i could nothing worked here lol



}
```

Please advice. I also apologize if this is a bad question.

Comment: use styling like margin-top:20px!important;

Comment: use the `vertical-align ="top"` . This will do that.

Comment: you need to create editable div in header and append the value to hidden input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a more stable / portable solution - simply move the filter input box around in the DOM :

add this to your initialization :

```
..
$('.dataTables_filter input').attr("placeholder", "enter seach terms here");
$('.dataTables_filter').css('float','none');    
$('.dataTables_filter').css('padding-right','0px');    
$("#example_filter").detach().prependTo('#header');
```

The above resets the default settings for the `dataTables_filter` so it can be centered in the `#header`. Remember to ad `id="header"` to your header, seems you have forgot that. Change the search toggle as well :

```
$('#search').click(function(e) {  
    $('#example_filter').toggle();    
    $('h1').toggle();
    if ($('#example_filter').is(':visible')) {
        $('.dataTables_filter').css("display", "inline-block");    
    } 
});
```

see forked fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/ynKed/**

Comment: i tried your soulution, although it woks on fiddle for some reason it does not on my actual code..i can show u my code if u wana see..my header goes completely blank..

Comment: Its OK, you have a fine solution. Anyway, I let the answer stay. Though the accepted answer fullfill your needs, it is narrowed to the specific scenario in the question. The above is for anyone who want to place their dataTables filter input in a `#header`-section, or in any other element for that matter.

Comment: i actually am having a slight issue with the accept  answer i commented under is it possible for you to take a look. i will also rep u.

Comment: @user2733436, could you create a new fiddle containing your "actual code"? I think the markup of the header / table (think we have it) and the complete CSS? There must be something that overrule each other.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3rR6J/106/ this is actually exactly what i am dealing with right now

Comment: it contains all the css i am using

Comment: forked -> http://jsfiddle.net/n8gHD/ it works here, I have only beautified the code, commented out the CSS z-index solution, inserted my own and set id=header. The last thing was the reason why the bar background disappeared.

Comment: start from http://jsfiddle.net/3rR6J/127/ and go back (126, 125 etc) to see my steps

Comment: hey by the way would u know how to change colors in datatables? i can't override css for some reason

Comment: @user2733436, see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/c32QC/ based on the example discussed here. Changes the colors for even, odd and selected column. Be sure your overriding CSS is implemented last, use `!important` where it not applies.

Comment: Thanks so much i should have asked u as a seprate question and give u rep i was just wondering in the header of the table there are arrows is it possible to change color of the arrow?

Comment: @user2733436, no they are images attached as `background-image`, but you can make your own images and replace them - guess simply just recolor them in a imageprocessing program.

Comment: hey i have just posted a new question, u helped me out earlier when i had issue with dataTables so if u can please take a look at my new issue i would highly appreciate it . Thanks again.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842504/datatables-updating-only-rows-without-reloading-table

Answer (score 4):

Add this style:

```
#example_filter {
   margin: 9px 0 0 -118px;
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 9999999;
   left: 50%;
   top: 0;
}
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3rR6J/58/)

Comment: kya baat hai! this saved me so much time.

Comment: Jai, i am actually having a slight issue for the changes u suggested. u said keep "position:fixed" however it is not letting my pannel work when i keep position fixed but when i change to "position:absolute" my panel is working fine but css is messed up again as the search bar is in the bottom not top. Can u provide solution where position is not fixed?

Comment: See this answer -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18639734/z-index-not-behaving-as-expected-with-absolute-positioning-inside-a-fixed-positi  - it is probably about stacking. There is way to many classes and elements with set or **computed** position as `fixed` / `absolute` nested into each other, to let the dataTables_filter stay on top of them all. It looked good before, though.

Comment: trying still not able to tweak mine to work not sure what to do. tried for past hour.