# Datatables updating only rows without reloading table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

**BACKGROUND:**
I have a small jquery app that contains widgets. There are 2  types of widgets in this app and they are counter widgets and grid widgets. For grid widgets i am utilizing [dataTables](https://datatables.net/).

My app basically connects to a server and recieves various information such as widget names etc. So based on the information received i dynamically create pages for each widget. Things are working fine at the moment but i am facing a little problem.

**Problem**
The issue i have right now is to do with my grid widgets which utilize dataTables api.From my server I receive the grid information in this format.

```
//EXAMPLE INPUT
/*
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<rows>

 <head>
 <column width="55" type="ro" align="left" sort="str">Player</column>
 <column width="55" type="ro" align="left" sort="str">State</column>
 <column width="55" type="ro" align="left" sort="str">Points</column>
 </head>
      <row id="1">
            <cell>Lebron King James</cell>
            <cell>Best Mode</cell>
            <cell>45</cell>
      </row>
</rows>
*/
```

Then i parse it to the appropriate table format (function createTableStringFromXML) so it works with the datatables.

My table is reloading every 3 seconds. So  this is the problem.

Eventhough i want my table to update i think reloading the entire table is bad because not only does it look weird but i think it is not necessary. I was wondering is there way i can write some function that compares the old table with the new updated table and only updates rows that need update? So this way the entire table it self is not loaded?

**MY HTML CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>NBA Fanatico</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/tdMobile.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.0.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssfinal/style.css" />


        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>


    <script src="dhtmxSuite/dhtmlxWindows/codebase/dhtmlxcommon.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

           <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
       <script src="jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>

   <!-- MAIN JS SCRIPT CONTANS CODE FOR COUTNER WIDGETS, TABLES , AJAX REQUEST FOR GETTING DATA-->

     <script src="dynamic.js"></script>



<!-- SCRIPTS FOR DATA TABLES -->

<!-- DataTables CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />



<!-- DataTables -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>




    </head>
    <body>

    <!-- PAGE 1 -->
        <div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="page1">
            <!-- <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
                <h1></h1>
            </div> -->


            <div data-role="content" data-theme="a">




          <div class="login-box" id="login">



             <div id="loginprompt">
                <div id="header">


            <h3>Basketball Fanatico</h3>

        </div>

                </div>
        <form method="GET">

                <div id="username" data-role="fieldcontain">     
                    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
                </div>
                <div id="password" data-role="fieldcontain">   
                   <input type="password" name="password" id="txtId" placeholder="Password"/>
                </div>
                <div id ="loginbtn">
                    <a data-role="button" id="log" data-theme="a" href="#page2" data-transition="slide">LOGIN</a>
                </div>
            </form>

            <br />


</div>

            </div>


            </div>

        </div>


<!-- PAGE 2 -->

<div data-role="page" id="page2">

  <div data-role ="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a"> 
    <a data-iconpos="notext" href="#panel" data-role="button" data-icon="bars"></a>

  <h1 class="ui-title" role="heading">Basketball Fanatico</h1>
    <div class="ui-btn-right"  data-type="horizontal">
      <a data-iconpos="notext" href="#page2" data-role="button" data-icon="home" ></a>
      <a data-iconpos="notext" href="#page1" data-role="button" data-icon="delete" ></a>
    </div>
</div>



            <div data-role="content" id="page2content"> 

                <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
                    <li data-role="list-divider" data-theme="a">WELCOME!</li>
                    <li>Use the menu on the left to navigate <br />and configure the various options.</li>                  
                </ul>


            </div>

        </div>

        <div data-role="panel" id="panel"  data-position="left" data-theme="a" data-display="push">
           <!--  <div> -->
                <div id="nav"><h3>Navigation</h3>


                 <hr>
                <label>

                <input id="chkSort" type="checkbox" checked="true"  />Allow sorting</input>
                </label>
                <hr>
            </div>
            <div id="items" data-role="button">
                <!-- Insert Parsed Widget Names Here -->
                <a href="#page1" data-transition="fade" data-theme="a" data-role="button">LOG OUT</a>
            </div>

        <!-- </div> -->


</div>



    </body>
</html>
```

**MY JS**

```
        var widgetNames = new Array();
        var widgetId = new Array();
        var pageId = ''



        $( document ).on( "pagecreate", function() {
            $( "body > [data-role='panel']" ).panel().enhanceWithin();


              //Format the grid as required
              $('#example2').dataTable( {
                "bPaginate": false,
                "bFilter": true,
                "bAutoWidth": false,
                "oLanguage": { "sSearch": "" } 
               } );

              $('.dataTables_filter input').attr("placeholder", "Search");
              $('.dataTables_filter').css('float','none');    
              $('.dataTables_filter').css('padding-right','0px');    
              $("#example_filter").detach().prependTo('#header1');    

        });

        $(document).on('pagecreate', '#page1', function() {

           // $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).on( "pagecontainershow", function( event, ui ) {
           //                    pageId = $('body').pagecontainer('getActivePage').prop("id"); 
           //                    alert( "The page id of this page is: " + pageId );
           //                    });


            $("#log").on('click', function(){

                $.ajax({
                    url: "script.login",
                        type: "GET",
                        data: { 'page':'create_user', 'access':'user','username':$("input[name='username']").val(), 'password':$("input[name='password']").val()},
                        dataType: "text",
                        success: function (html) {
                            //console.log(html);


                            widgetNames = new Array();
                            widgetId = new Array();
                            var res = html.match(/insertNewChild(.*);/g);



                            //Get each widget name and ID and assign to values in an array
                            for(var i =0;i<res.length;i++){
                                //alert(res[i]);
                                var temp = res[i].split(',');
                                if(temp.length >= 3){
                                  widgetNames[i] = (temp[2].replace('");','')).replace('"','');
                                  widgetId[i] = temp[1].replace("'","").replace("'","").replace(/ /g,'');
                                }           
                            }

                            var AllWidgets = ''
                            var testwidget = new Array();



                            //Loop through the html returned and get the data relevant to each widget... save in temp array                            
                            var tempWidgetContent = html.match(/w\d+\.isHidden(.*)\(\) == false\)[\s\S]*?catch\(err\)\{ \}/gm);
                            for(var i =0;i<tempWidgetContent.length;i++){
                                  var widgetContent = tempWidgetContent[i].substring(tempWidgetContent[i].indexOf('{')+1);
                                 //alert(widgetContent);

                                 //This alone handles coutners...
                                  testwidget[i] = widgetContent.replace("site +","");

                                  //replace the code for a grids...
                                  if(testwidget[i].indexOf('grid') > 0){

                                    testwidget[i] = CreateGridUpdateFunction(testwidget[i],i);
                                  }


                            }



                            var widgetPart =  new Array();

                            //Assume we have widget names, ids, and loading data in 3 arrays
                            //Loop through and create the necessary page.
                            for(var i = 0; i<widgetNames.length; i++){




                              if(testwidget[i].indexOf('hi') > -1){
                                // alert('WORKING');
                                var pageHeaderPart = "<div data-role= 'page' id='"+widgetId[i]+"' data-pageindex='"+i+"' class='dynPageClass'><div data-role='header' id='header1' data-position='fixed' data-theme='a'><a href='#panel' data-icon='bars' data-iconpos='notext' class='ui-btn-left'></a><a href='#' data-icon='search' id='search' data-iconpos='notext' class='ui-btn-left' style='margin-left: 35px'></a><h1>BASKETBALL FANATICO</h1><a href='#page1' data-icon='delete' data-iconpos='notext' class='ui-btn-right'></a><a href='#page2' data-icon='home' data-iconpos='notext' class='ui-btn-right' style='margin-right: 35px;'></a></div><div data-role='content'>";
                              }

                              else{

                               var pageHeaderPart = "<div data-role='page' id='"+widgetId[i]+"' data-pageindex='"+i+"' class='dynPageClass'><div data-role='header'data-position='fixed' data-theme='a'><a data-iconpos='notext' href='#panel' data-role='button'data-icon='bars'></a><h1 class='ui-title'role='heading'>BASKETBALL FANATICO</h1><div class='ui-btn-right' data-type='horizontal'><a data-iconpos='notext' href='#page2' data-role='button'data-icon='home'style=\" margin-right:5px; \"></a><a data-iconpos='notext' href='#page1' data-role='button'data-icon='delete'></a></div></div><div data-role='content'>";
                              }


                               var pageFooterPart = "</div><div data-role='footer' data-position='fixed'><span class='ui-title'><div id='navigator'></div></span></div></div>";


                               if(testwidget[i].indexOf('hi') > -1){
                                   // alert('i am a grid');

                               var check = "<div data-role='tbcontent'><ul data-role='listview'data-insert='true'><li data-role='list-divider' data-theme='a'>"+widgetNames[i]+"";

                               }


                               var check = "<div data-role='content'><ul data-role='listview'data-insert='true'><li data-role='list-divider' data-theme='a'>"+widgetNames[i]+"</div>";

                               if(testwidget[i].indexOf('counterValue') > 0){
                                 // alert('i am a counter');

                                  widgetPart[i] = '<DIV style=\" text-align: center; background-color:#EDEDED; padding-bottom: auto;  font-size: 55pt;\" id=widgetContainer_'+widgetId[i]+'></DIV><SCRIPT>' + 'function UpdateWidgetDiv'+widgetId[i]+'() {' + testwidget[i] + '$(\"#widgetContainer_'+widgetId[i]+'").html(counterValue);' + '}' + '</SCRIPT>';




                               }
                               if(testwidget[i].indexOf('hi') > -1){
                                // alert('i am a grid');

                                   widgetPart[i] = '<DIV id=widgetContainer_'+widgetId[i]+'></DIV><SCRIPT>' + 'function UpdateWidgetDiv'+widgetId[i]+'() {' + testwidget[i]  + '}' + '</SCRIPT>';
                               }
                               else {
                                  widgetPart[i] = '<DIV style=\" text-align: center; background-color:#EDEDED; padding-bottom: auto;  font-size: 55pt;\" id=widgetContainer_'+widgetId[i]+'>I dont know what I am</DIV>';
                               }

                               AllWidgets +='<a href="#'+widgetId[i]+'" class="widgetLink" data-theme="b" data-role="button" >'+widgetNames[i]+'</a>';                         

                                             var makePage = $(pageHeaderPart + check + widgetPart[i] + pageFooterPart);

                               makePage.appendTo($.mobile.pageContainer);
                            }
                            $('#items').prepend(AllWidgets).trigger('create');


//Widget Update Function

function UpdateActivePage(){
    //get active page
    pageId = $(":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer('getActivePage').prop("id");
    //figure out index
    var idx;
    for (var i=0; i<widgetId.length; i++){
       if (widgetId[i] == pageId){
          idx = i;
          break;
       }
    }

//alert(pageId);
    //run your update
    //alert("RUNNING:");
    eval(testwidget[idx]);
    //alert('Updateing active page');
    $("#widgetContainer_" + pageId).html(counterValue);


        $('#grid_'+idx).dataTable( { 
          "bPaginate": false,
          "bFilter": true,
          "bAutoWidth": false,
          "oLanguage": { "sSearch": "" } 
        } );
       $('.dataTables_filter input').attr("placeholder", "Search");
       $('.dataTables_filter').css('float','none');  
       $('.dataTables_filter').css('padding-right','0px');   
       $("#example_filter").detach().prependTo('#header1');   


}


function CreateGridUpdateFunction(oldUpdatefunction,thisWidgetID)
{




    var updateLines = oldUpdatefunction.split("\n");
    var updateFunctionCode = "";
    for (var i=0; i<updateLines.length;i++)
    {
        if(updateLines[i].indexOf(" var url = ") > 0)
        {

            var updateURL = updateLines[i];
            if(updateURL.indexOf("&windowWidth=") > 0){
                updateURL = updateURL.substr(0,updateURL.lastIndexOf("&windowWidth=")) + "';";

            }

            updateFunctionCode += updateURL;   
            updateFunctionCode += "   var loader = dhtmlxAjax.getSync(url);";   
            updateFunctionCode += "   if(loader.xmlDoc.responseText.length > 0){";

            updateFunctionCode += "     counterValue = createTableStringFromXML(loader.xmlDoc.responseText,"+thisWidgetID+");";
            updateFunctionCode += "   }   ";


        }
    }


    return "var counterValue = \"hi\"; "+updateFunctionCode ; 
}


$(":mobile-pagecontainer" ).on( "pagechange", function()  { UpdateActivePage(); } )



setInterval(UpdateActivePage, 3000);



                        }

                });

            });
        });



//Returns a bool indicated if the (space trimmed) string starts with needle.
function startsWith(searchString,searchVal){
  var search = searchString.trim();
  return search.indexOf(searchVal) >= 0;
}

function createTableStringFromXML(serverXML,thisWidgetID){


  console.log(serverXML);

  var xmlLines = serverXML.split("\n");
  var returnTable = "";


  for (var i=0; i<xmlLines.length;i++)
  {
     if(startsWith(xmlLines[i],"<rows"))
     {
        returnTable += "<table cellpadding=\"2\"  cellspacing=\"2\" border=\"0\" class=\"display\" id=\"grid_"+thisWidgetID+"\" width=\"100%\">";
     }
     else if(startsWith(xmlLines[i],"</rows>"))
     {
        returnTable += "</tbody></table>";
     }
     else if(startsWith(xmlLines[i],"<head>"))
     {
        returnTable += "<thead><tr>";
     }
     else if(startsWith(xmlLines[i],"</head>"))
     {
        returnTable += "</tr></thead><tbody>";
     }
     else if(startsWith(xmlLines[i],"<column"))
     {
        returnTable += "<th>"+xmlLines[i].match(/>(.*?)</i)[1]+"</th>";
     }
     else if(startsWith(xmlLines[i],"<row"))
     {
        returnTable += "<tr>";
     }
     else if(startsWith(xmlLines[i],"</row"))
     {
        returnTable += "</tr>";
     }     
     else if(startsWith(xmlLines[i],"<cell"))
     {
        returnTable += "<td>"+xmlLines[i].match(/>(.*?)</i)[1]+"</td>";
     }


console.log(returnTable);

  }


   return returnTable ;

}
```

**Please advice** on how to achieve this. I am sorry if you have not understood my question so please ask me again. I am only using HTML and JS for couple of months so i am band new to this and that also might be the reason why my question might sound silly to some of you so sorry in advance. I apologize for my poor english please let me know if you dont understand. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like it's better to reload the whole table, you collecting all data anyways. Loop through the table to look for differences sounds like a little overkill. However, sure is possible. You need 2 js arrays afaik and the keys should be the name as it doesnt change. Then compare the values state and points to find differences. That should be done in a loop. You might wanna request the data as an array too. Hope this points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating the table every 3 seconds could cause performance issues, especially if you have lots of rows!

If you want to do it, you can iterate through the rows in the update XML and then write the values to the individual cells in the table.

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/9q7ve/)**

In my example, the table is already there with row ids as data attributes on the row element.  I am updating once on a button click instead of every 3 seconds on a timer, but the parsing would be the same.

```
$("#update").on("click", function(){
    var $trows= $('#example tbody tr');       
    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xmlstring );
    var $xml = $( xmlDoc );  

    $xml.find("row").each(function(index){            
        var id = $(this).prop("id");            
        var $cells = $(this).find("cell");
        var c1 = $cells.eq(0).text();
        var c2 = $cells.eq(1).text();
        var c3 = $cells.eq(2).text();

        //get row in table with this id
        var $rowtd = $('#example tbody [data-id=' + id + '] td');
        $rowtd.eq(0).text(c1);
        $rowtd.eq(1).text(c2);
        $rowtd.eq(2).text(c3);
    });  
});
```

The code loads the XML string into an XmlDocument and then creates a jQuery object from the document. Next I iterate through all the Xml Nodes called "row" getting the id and the 3 cell texts. Then I find the row in the existing table with the same Id and write the texts into the existind TDs in the row.

You will need to test the performance of this given the normal number of rows you have and the types of devices you plan to support.

Comment: Hi, Thanks so much for the solution just 1 question in this case you are assuming you only have 3 rows of data right but in my case rows can vary as i am dynamically creating grids so how would this exactly be implemented in my case.

Yea i will definitely test this for performance...

Comment: The .each function does not care how many rows there are in the XML, it steps through all of them. In my example I only included 3 rows, but you can have any number.

Comment: i tried implementing this in my code not sure how to is it possible to show me in my posted code above?

Comment: Your code is hard to understand, if you create a simplified fiddle we can try to edit it. Basically You would still call createTableStringFromXML on first load to create your datatable as you do now. Then wherever your update timer is, you would still make the same ajax call to get the xml. Now, on the ajax success, instead of creating the table again, you would use my code to iterate through the xml and update the existing table cells.

Comment: Hi, i have re-posted my question here and i think i have better highlighted the real issue i am having. if you can take a look i will be very grateful this is the only issue stopping me from finishing the app. Thanks
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22938579/sorting-and-searching-datatables-after-refreshing-table

Comment: I have been trying entire weekend and i had no luck. really stuck on this.

Comment: Instead of posting all your code which probably no one will read due to how long it is, try to make a smaller project in jsFiddle that only reproduces your problem and not your entire app. You could update my fiddle if you want.

Comment: Well i don't know how exactly to show my app in the fiddle because i am updating every 3 seconds and getting new data and sometimes even a new row can get added. for example say u start with a grid that shows stats of 2 players after 3 seconds another players stats can also be added. So how exactly can we simulate this in the fiddle you have already created?

Comment: Look here: http://datatables.net/api if you use fnUpdate to update rows/cells, the table automatically resorts. In this updated fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/9q7ve/1/) sort by points and then click the button.  Use fnAddData when you need to add rows.

Comment: Hi, This is very good i was looking for some solution like this. There is only 1 problem though what if on a update a row gets deleted so say after update "lebron james" and his entire row is deleted . Also what if a row for some new player is added after an update? How to handle this?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/9q7ve/2/ Use fnClearTable(); to remove all existing rows and then fnAddData to add each row from the XML. This takes care of deleting, adding, and updating while keeping the current sorting.

Comment: Well my concern is when i am getting an update how do i check if there are new rows and which rows are deleted? like i know what u did in the fiddle update but my concern is how will i check with real time data?Thanks again.

Comment: In my last example you don't need to check, fnClearTable removes all rows, then you add all rows from the new XML. THis will automatically handle delete, add, and update.

Comment: so basically it has its own compare function built in that does the checking for you?

Comment: no, you are literally removing all rows and rebuilding the table from scratch; however, by using the datatables api, you maintain all other datatables settings like sort column, etc.

Comment: so would this be bad if there is a lot of data? because we are rebuilding all the time...i mean is there any other way around this? just wondering in general.?

Comment: It would be bad either way. If you do not clear the table, you would need to parse the XML into an array or hashtable of rows, then iterate the datatable. For each row in the datatable, if found in array, update and remove from array, if not found in array, remove from table, anything left over in the array, add to the table. That is probably more processing than just clearing and re-adding.

Comment: oh okay yea i see what you mean so i guess in terms of processing this is probably more efficient since we are clearing every time. comparing  values from table to table would be overkill i guess.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am thinking.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23245624/swiping-pages-in-jquery
Hi i just posted this new question its the code you provided me earlier just needed very tiny help if u can take a look it would be awesome . thanks

Comment: The fiddle is also there in it. I just need a slight modification for swiping. if u can please take a look.