# Swiping Pages in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a small app here which consist of a welcome page and a few other pages for various teams. Here is my [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/w5j2E/) i have to make things easy. PLEASE check it out.

In this i can swipe from the welcome page to miami heat to new york knicks to houston rockets and back to welcome page. The thing is i don't want users to be able to swipe from houston rockets page back to welcome page. So i was wondering how can i do that?

The following is my code i use for swiping through pages.

```
   $("#items").sortable({
          stop: function( event, ui ) {
              teamNames = [];
              teamId = [];
              $(".teamLink").each(function() {
                  var href = $(this).prop('href');
                  var name = $(this).text();
                  var id = href.substr(href.lastIndexOf("#") + 1);
                  teamId.push(id);
                  teamNames.push(name)
              });
              alert(teamNames);
              $("#items").listview('refresh');
          }
    }).disableSelection();

    $("#chkSort").on("change", function(){
        var sort = $(this).prop("checked");
        if (sort){
            $( "#items" ).sortable('enable');
        } else {
            $("#items").sortable('disable');
        }

    });

    $(document).on("swipeleft", "#page2", function() {
       $.mobile.changePage("#"+teamId[0], {transition: "slide", reverse: false});
    });        
});


    $(document).on("swiperight swipeleft", ".dynPageClass", function(e) {
        var curPageID = $(this).prop("id");
        var ind=0;
        for(var i = 0; i<teamId.length; i++){
            if (curPageID == teamId[i]){
                ind = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        var topageid = "page2";
        var rev = true;
        if (e.type == 'swiperight'){
            if (ind > 0){
                topageid = teamId[ind - 1] ; 
            }
        } else {
            rev = false;
            if (ind < teamId.length - 1){
                topageid = teamId[ind + 1] ; 
            }            
        }
        $.mobile.changePage("#" + topageid, {transition: "slide", reverse: rev});
    });
```

**Following is code with the updated code for adjusting FOOTER.**

```
        var widgetNames = new Array();
        var widgetId = new Array();
        var pageId = ''




        $( document ).on( "pagecreate", function() {
            $( "body > [data-role='panel']" ).panel().enhanceWithin();










        });

        $(document).on('pagecreate', '#page1', function() {



            $("#log").on('click', function(){



                $.ajax({
                    url: "script.login",
                        type: "GET",
                        data: { 'page':'create_user', 'access':'user','username':$("input[name='username']").val(), 'password':$("input[name='password']").val()},
                        dataType: "text",
                        success: function (html) {



                            widgetNames = new Array();
                            widgetId = new Array();
                            var res = html.match(/insertNewChild(.*);/g);




                            for(var i =0;i<res.length;i++){

                                var temp = res[i].split(',');
                                if(temp.length >= 3){
                                  widgetNames[i] = (temp[2].replace('");','')).replace('"','');
                                  widgetId[i] = temp[1].replace("'","").replace("'","").replace(/ /g,'');
                                }           
                            }

                            var AllWidgets = ''
                            var testwidget = new Array();



                            var tempWidgetContent = html.match(/w\d+\.isHidden(.*)\(\) == false\)[\s\S]*?catch\(err\)\{ \}/gm);
                            for(var i =0;i<tempWidgetContent.length;i++){
                                  var widgetContent = tempWidgetContent[i].substring(tempWidgetContent[i].indexOf('{')+1);

                                  testwidget[i] = widgetContent.replace("site +","");


                                  if(testwidget[i].indexOf('grid') > 0){

                                    testwidget[i] = CreateGridUpdateFunction(testwidget[i],i);
                                  }


                            }



                            var widgetPart =  new Array();


                            for(var i = 0; i<widgetNames.length; i++){








                              if(testwidget[i].substring(0,3)== "var"){
                                // alert('WORKING');
                                var pageHeaderPart = "<div data-role= 'page' id='"+widgetId[i]+"' data-pageindex='"+i+"' class='dynPageClass'><div data-role='header' id='header1' data-position='fixed' data-theme='a'><a href='#panel' data-icon='bars'  data-iconpos='notext' class='ui-btn-left'></a><a data-icon='search' id='searchicon_"+i+"' data-iconpos='notext' class='ui-btn-left' style='margin-left: 35px'></a><h1 id='test1'>Basketball Fanatico</h1><a href='#page1' data-icon='delete' data-iconpos='notext' class='ui-btn-right'></a><a href='#page2' data-icon='home' data-iconpos='notext' class='ui-btn-right' style='margin-right: 35px;'></a></div><div data-role='content'>";
                              }

                              else{

                               var pageHeaderPart = "<div data-role='page' id='"+widgetId[i]+"' data-pageindex='"+i+"' class='dynPageClass'><div data-role='header'data-position='fixed' data-theme='a'><a data-iconpos='notext' href='#panel' data-role='button'data-icon='bars'></a><h1 class='ui-title'role='heading'>Basketball Fanatico</h1><div class='ui-btn-right' data-type='horizontal'><a data-iconpos='notext' href='#page2' data-role='button'data-icon='home'style=\" margin-right:5px; \"></a><a data-iconpos='notext' href='#page1' data-role='button'data-icon='delete'></a></div></div><div data-role='content'>";
                              }


                               var pageFooterPart = "</div><div data-role='footer' data-position='fixed' id='footer'  ><span class='ui-title'><div id='navigator'></div></span></div></div>";


                               if(testwidget[i].substring(0,3)== "var"){
                                   // alert('i am a grid');

                               var check = "<div data-role='tbcontent'><ul data-role='listview'data-insert='true'><li data-role='list-divider' data-theme='a'>"+widgetNames[i]+"";

                               }


                               var check = "<div data-role='content' id='widgname'><ul data-role='listview'data-insert='true'><li data-role='list-divider' data-theme='a'>"+widgetNames[i]+"</div>";

                               if(testwidget[i].substring(11,31)== "var counterValue = 0"){
                                 // alert('i am a counter');

                                  widgetPart[i] = '<DIV style=\" text-align: center; background-color:#EDEDED; padding-bottom: auto;  font-size: 55pt;\" id=widgetContainer_'+widgetId[i]+'></DIV><SCRIPT>' + 'function UpdateWidgetDiv'+widgetId[i]+'() {' + testwidget[i] + '$(\"#widgetContainer_'+widgetId[i]+'").html(counterValue);' + '}' + '</SCRIPT>';



                               }
                               if(testwidget[i].substring(0,3)== "var"){


                                   widgetPart[i] = '<DIV id=widgetContainer_'+widgetId[i]+'></DIV><SCRIPT>' + 'function UpdateWidgetDiv'+widgetId[i]+'() {' +testwidget[i]  + '}' + '</SCRIPT>';
                               }


                               else{




                               }

                               AllWidgets +='<a href="#'+widgetId[i]+'" class="widgetLink" data-theme="b" data-role="button" >'+widgetNames[i]+'</a>';                         

                               var makePage = $(pageHeaderPart + check + widgetPart[i] + pageFooterPart);

                               makePage.appendTo($.mobile.pageContainer);
                            }
                            $('#items').prepend(AllWidgets).trigger('create');





function UpdateActivePage(){

    pageId = $(":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer('getActivePage').prop("id");

    var idx;
    for (var i=0; i<widgetId.length; i++){
       if (widgetId[i] == pageId){
          idx = i;
          break;
       }
    }


    eval(testwidget[idx]);

     if (counterValue == false) {
                        //no need to recreate datatable
                        return;
                    } else {






    $("#widgetContainer_" + pageId).html(counterValue);



        $('#grid_'+idx).dataTable( { 
          "bPaginate": false,
          "bFilter": true,
          "bAutoWidth": false,
          "oLanguage": { "sSearch": "" } 
        } );
       $('.dataTables_filter input').attr("placeholder", "Search");
       $('.dataTables_filter').css('float','none');  
       $('.dataTables_filter').css('padding-right','0px');



$("#grid_"+idx+"_filter").css('display', 'none'); 




 $('#searchicon_'+i).click(function() {  

var searchwidth1  = $("#widgetContainer_"+widgetId[i]).width();


var searchwidth1 = searchwidth1 - 20;

   $('#grid_'+idx+'_filter').toggle();  

$("#grid_"+idx+"_filter :input").css('width', searchwidth1 + 'px');  


});





}



}







function CreateGridUpdateFunction(oldUpdatefunction,thisWidgetID)
{



    var updateLines = oldUpdatefunction.split("\n");
    var updateFunctionCode = "";
    for (var i=0; i<updateLines.length;i++)
    {
        if(updateLines[i].indexOf(" var url = ") > 0)
        {


            var updateURL = updateLines[i];
            if(updateURL.indexOf("&windowWidth=") > 0){
                updateURL = updateURL.substr(0,updateURL.lastIndexOf("&windowWidth=")) + "';";

            }

            updateFunctionCode += updateURL;   
            updateFunctionCode += "   var loader = dhtmlxAjax.getSync(url);";   
            updateFunctionCode += "   if(loader.xmlDoc.responseText.length > 0){";

            updateFunctionCode += "     counterValue = createTableStringFromXML(loader.xmlDoc.responseText,"+thisWidgetID+");";
            updateFunctionCode += "   }   ";

        }
    }


    return "var counterValue = \"\"; "+updateFunctionCode ; 
}


$(":mobile-pagecontainer" ).on( "pagechange", function()  { UpdateActivePage(); } )


setInterval(UpdateActivePage, 3000);




                        }

                });

            });
        });


function startsWith(searchString,searchVal){

  console.log(searchString);
  var search = searchString.trim();
  return search.indexOf(searchVal) >= 0;
}

function createTableStringFromXML(serverXML,thisWidgetID){





  console.log(serverXML);

  var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(serverXML);
  var $xml = $( xmlDoc );



  var xmlLines = serverXML.split("\n");
  var returnTable = "";


 if ( $("#grid_" + thisWidgetID).length > 0){



         var oTable = $("#grid_" + thisWidgetID).dataTable();
        oTable.fnClearTable();


        $xml.find("row").each(function(index){            
            var $cells = $(this).find("cell");
            var rowData = [];
            $cells.each(function(cellIndex){
                rowData.push($(this).text());
            });            
            oTable.fnAddData( rowData);
        });




        return false;
    } else {







  for (var i=0; i<xmlLines.length;i++)
  {
     if(startsWith(xmlLines[i],"<rows"))
     {
        returnTable += "<table cellpadding=\"2\"  cellspacing=\"2\" border=\"0\" class=\"display\" id=\"grid_"+thisWidgetID+"\" width=\"100%\">";
     }
     else if(startsWith(xmlLines[i],"</rows>"))
     {
        returnTable += "</tbody></table>";
     }
     else if(startsWith(xmlLines[i],"<head>"))
     {
        returnTable += "<thead><tr>";
     }
     else if(startsWith(xmlLines[i],"</head>"))
     {
        returnTable += "</tr></thead><tbody>";
     }
     else if(startsWith(xmlLines[i],"<column"))
     {
        returnTable += "<th>"+xmlLines[i].match(/>(.*?)</i)[1]+"</th>";
     }
     else if(startsWith(xmlLines[i],"<row"))
     {
        returnTable += "<tr>";
     }
     else if(startsWith(xmlLines[i],"</row"))
     {
        returnTable += "</tr>";
     }     
     else if(startsWith(xmlLines[i],"<cell"))
     {
        returnTable += "<td>"+xmlLines[i].match(/>(.*?)</i)[1]+"</td>";
     }



console.log(returnTable);


  }



}
   return returnTable ;




}




//CODE FOR DRAG AND DROP AND SWIPING  DYNAMICALLY CREATED PAGES




        $(document).on('pagecreate', '#page2', function() {

            $("#items").sortable({
                  stop: function( event, ui ) {
                      widgetNames = [];
                      widgetId = [];
                      $(".widgetLink").each(function() {
                          var href = $(this).prop('href');
                          var name = $(this).text();
                          var id = href.substr(href.lastIndexOf("#") + 1);
                          widgetId.push(id);
                          widgetNames.push(name)
                      });
                      //alert(widgetNames);
                      $("#items").listview('refresh');
                  }
            }).disableSelection();

            $("#chkSort").on("change", function(){
                var sort = $(this).prop("checked");
                if (sort){
                    $( "#items" ).sortable('enable');
                } else {
                    $("#items").sortable('disable');
                }

            });

            $(document).on("swipeleft", "#page2", function() {
               $.mobile.changePage("#"+widgetId[0], {transition: "slide", reverse: false});
            });        

            $(document).on("swiperight swipeleft", ".dynPageClass", function(e) {
                var curPageID = $(this).prop("id");
                var ind=0;
                for(var i = 0; i<widgetId.length; i++){
                    if (curPageID == widgetId[i]){
                        ind = i;
                        break;
                    }


                }

                var topageid = "page2";
                var rev = true;
                if (e.type == 'swiperight'){
                    if (ind > 0){
                        topageid = widgetId[ind - 1] ; 
                    }
                } else {
                    rev = false;
                    if (ind < widgetId.length - 1){
                        topageid = widgetId[ind + 1] ; 
                    }   else {
                      topageid = null;
                    }
                }if(topageid){
                $.mobile.changePage("#" + topageid, {transition: "slide", reverse: rev});
                }
            });         

        });



//ADJUST FOOTER

$(document).on("pagecontainershow", function () {
    SetMinHeight();
});

$(window).on("resize orientationchange", function () {
    SetMinHeight();
});

function SetMinHeight() {
    var screen = $.mobile.getScreenHeight();
    var header = $(".ui-header").hasClass("ui-header-fixed") ? $(".ui-header").outerHeight() - 1 : $(".ui-header").outerHeight();
    var footer = $(".ui-footer").hasClass("ui-footer-fixed") ? $(".ui-footer").outerHeight() - 1 : $(".ui-footer").outerHeight();
    var contentCurrent = $(".ui-content").outerHeight() - $(".ui-content").height();

    var content = screen - header - footer - contentCurrent;
    $(".ui-content").css("min-height", content + "px");
}
```

**Following is my css**

```
.login-box {
    margin: auto;
    padding: auto;
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(241, 241, 241);
    border: 1px solid rgb(229, 229, 229);
    width:300px;
}


.ui-field-contain {

    border-bottom-width: 0px;

}

#loginbtn {

    text-align: center;
    width: 150px;
    margin:  auto;


}

#loginprompt{
text-align: right;
}

#loginprompt h4{
text-align: left;
font-size: 14px;
}
#header{
    text-align: center;

}

#header h5{

    color: #373E4A;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: Courier;


}

#header h3{

    font-family: sans-serif;
}

#login{

width: 85%;
    margin:auto;
}


#icons{
    text-align: right;
}

#icons{  
 text-align: right; 
   clear:both; 
} 

#icons .left{

    float: left;
    padding-top:5px;
    margin: 2px;


}



#nav hr{
    width: 119%;
}


a#log.ui-link.ui-btn.ui-btn-a.ui-shadow.ui-corner-all {
    background-color: #4289C1;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}


}
.ui-panel {
    bottom: 0 !important;



}
.ui-panel-inner{
    padding-top: 0 !important;
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
    padding-left: 4px !important;    
    padding-right: 30px !important;
    height: 98% !important;
    overflow: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.ui-panel-inner .ui-btn {
    white-space: normal;
    font-size: 15px;
    width: 170px;
}

.ui-btn.ui-corner-all.ui-btn-inherit.ui-btn-icon-left.ui-checkbox-on{
    width: 150px;
}

#example_filter{
display: none;


}

label{


width: 140px;

}


#example_wrapper{

margin: auto;

}



#example_filter{

margin: -5px 0 0  90px;



}



table.dataTable tr.odd td.sorting_1 {
   background-color: #E3EEF8 !important;

}


table.dataTable tr.even td.sorting_1{
    background-color: white !important;

    text-shadow:none !important;

}

table.dataTable  tr.odd {
    background-color: #E3EEF8!important;
    text-shadow: none !important;

}
table.dataTable tr.even {
    background-color: white !important;
}

.sorting_asc {
background-color: #E3EEF8 !important;

}

#sclassic{
    width: 50px;       
}

h6{
    text-align: center;

}
```

Comment: I think you should be able to capture your e.type, and if (e.type == 'swipeleft' && $(this).find('.ui-li-divider') == 'Houston Rockets') then just return false. Please let me know if this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it:

> **[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/w5j2E/2/)**

If you are on the last page, set topageid equal to null. Then check that topageid is not null before calling changepage:

```
  if (e.type == 'swiperight'){
        if (ind > 0){
            topageid = teamId[ind - 1] ; 
        }
    } else {
        rev = false;
        if (ind < teamId.length - 1){
            topageid = teamId[ind + 1] ; 
        } else {
            //don't go back to page2
            topageid = null;
        }
    }
    if (topageid){
        $.mobile.changePage("#" + topageid, {transition: "slide", reverse: rev});
    }
```

Comment: Thanks that works but i found an unique issue, for some reason the swiping is smooth on iphone 5 i have but when i use my nexus 4 kit kat android based phone the swiping is not smooth . Do u know what can be reason for this?I tried looking online couldnt find much about such a issue....

Comment: i don't know about specific device issues.

Comment: do u have any suggestions as to how i can resolve that issue?

Comment: You can try this: http://chrissilich.com/blog/fix-css-animation-slow-or-choppy-in-mobile-browsers/ but I don't know if it will help. Also look at androind issue e.g. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17352

Comment: how exactly would i apply webkit-transform: translate  to my css?do u understand that?

Comment: Try applying it to the divs with data-role=page. It probably won't make much difference...

Comment: Hi, i just posted another css related question is it possible for you to look ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23252400/css-footer-div-wont-hide

Comment: yea they don't work, they work in the fiddle i created but not on actual code. In my actual code this is not a solution and what ends up happening is that the footer div ends up being placed halfway in the middle when i get rid of data-position="fixed"

Comment: is it possible for you to provide some generic answer that will work? i can post my code here too if u like.

Comment: See  Mozammil's last comment and fiddle. You just need to call that each time the table is refreshed because the number of rows can change.

Comment: Hey i tried to implement his code but it does not seem to work. This is my code from before is it possible for you to show me where to ad this code and how to call it ever time there is a refresh. I would appreciate a lot thanks.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22938579/sorting-and-searching-datatables-after-refreshing-table

Comment: Also u can post the answer under the original question and ill accept your answer.

Comment: i am trying and its not working =/. i added the css and used the code provided by mozammil no luck. if u can please help.

Comment: Would a code like this work?
$(document).on('focus', 'Table', function() 
{
  $.mobile.activePage.find("div[data-role='footer']").hide();
});

Comment: i found a better solution using min-height on the content div and posted that as an answer.

Comment: Hey i just tried your solution and what ended up happening is my content also got pushed to the bottom with the footer...

Comment: That does not happen in the fiddle, so you must have some CSS somewhere that affects your content...

Comment: i checked i am not sure. is it possible if i post my css and js you can guide me? or even if u can help me implement the other solution posted by the other user.

Comment: I have posted my code with the code u gave me for fixing the footer. i have also posted my css. is it possible to see what can be causing issue?

Comment: okay i seem to have sucess of being able to hide the footer on every page by using this
$(document).on("pagecontainershow", function () {


    $.mobile.activePage.find("div[data-role='footer']").hide();
});

Now i just want to be able to hide it if there are more than x rows in a table. how to do this?

Comment: ^ i think this will be most simple approach. so basically if i detect x # of rows then call this  $.mobile.activePage.find("div[data-role='footer']").hide(); --> AND hide the footer.

Comment: any suggestions? please help.