# CSS footer div won't hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

In this sample app I have a header , footer and the content div contains a table which holds various stats of some basketball players.

I was having a problem with the footer when i have a lot of entries in the table. What ends up happening is that the footer will block the other entries as displayed in the picture below.

[image]

Then when i click in the middle the footer disappears as shown in picture below.

[image]

I was wondering if there is generic way where i can check to see if there are a lot of entries then dont show the footer at all? or is there some way around this problem? Please advice i am new to web dev and dont know much css tricks.

Here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jzByk/).

This is roughly what i want to achieve, however i am not sure if its the best solution so i am open to all suggestions.

```
    if table contains > x entries 
    {

     hide footer

    } else {

      show footer

    }
```

Comment: The footer should not be fixed

Comment: In my actual code this is not a solution and what ends up happening is that the footer div ends up being placed halfway in the middle when i get rid of data-position="fixed"

Comment: Is the footer fixed? `data-position="fixed"`?

Comment: yes but i am being told to get rid of it and when i do it works fine on the demo fiddle but not my actual code. that's why i was looking for another solution.

Comment: I would really suggest getting a demo that works exactly as the live version does. Otherwise everyone here on SO is going to be shooting in the dark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best solution for you is to remove the data-position="fixed" on the footer as suggested by others, but then also add some javascript that sets the min-height of the content div according to device height. That way for a small number of rows in the table, the footer still appears at the bottom of the screen. As the number of rows increases beyond the device height, the footer just gets pushed down remaining below the table.

Below, the SetMinHeight function calculates the minimum height for the content div that would fill the given device height. Then you call it on pagecontainershow and whenever the window resizes or the orientation changes:

```
$(document).on("pagecontainershow", function () {
    SetMinHeight();
});

$(window).on("resize orientationchange", function () {
    SetMinHeight();
});

function SetMinHeight() {
    var screen = $.mobile.getScreenHeight();
    var header = $(".ui-header").hasClass("ui-header-fixed") ? $(".ui-header").outerHeight() - 1 : $(".ui-header").outerHeight();
    var footer = $(".ui-footer").hasClass("ui-footer-fixed") ? $(".ui-footer").outerHeight() - 1 : $(".ui-footer").outerHeight();
    var contentCurrent = $(".ui-content").outerHeight() - $(".ui-content").height();

    var content = screen - header - footer - contentCurrent;
    $(".ui-content").css("min-height", content + "px");
}
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jzByk/3/)**

**NOTE:** for the calc to work, I had to remove the CSS zoom:  #tbcontent{zoom:80%;}.  If you really need the zoom, you may have to adjust the min-height calculation...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7X6Fn/ This is what happens when i dont set data-position = fixed. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The footer shouldn't be fixed:

http://jsfiddle.net/fmpeyton/L2vQ3/

Remove `data-position='fixed'` from this line:

Comment: In my actual code this is not a solution and what ends up happening is that the footer div ends up being placed halfway in the middle when i get rid of data-position="fixed"

Comment: In the JSFiddle it fixes the issue, so there might be something else missing from the fiddle you provided us.

Comment: would something like this work???
$(document).on('focus', 'Table', function() 
{
  $.mobile.activePage.find("div[data-role='footer']").hide();
});

Comment: yes its not working most likely because i am using it incorrectly.

Comment: Jquery Mobile does a lot of leg work to the DOM when it initializes a page, so making DOM changes after it initializes isn't suggested. I would suggest removing the `data-position="fixed"` and fixing the footer. Just so we're fixing the problem itself and not a side effect of the problem.

Comment: This is what happens when i dont have data-postion="fixed"

Comment: I'm not seeing what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can check the number of rows in that table with something like this:

```
var rowCount = $('#myTable tr').length;
```

Then add a condition such as if rowCount > 5, you can add a hidden class to the footer.

A hidden class can be something like this:

```
.hidden { display: none; }
```

So basically,

```
if(rowCount > x) { $('.footer').addClass('hidden'); }
```

Comment: I think this solution might work is it possible for u to update my fiddle and show me this working

Comment: would something like this work??? $(document).on('focus', 'Table', function() { $.mobile.activePage.find("div[data-role='footer']").hide(); })

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var tablerow = $("table tr").length-1;
    if(tablerow>20)
    {
        $(".ui-title").hide();             
    }
    else
    {
        $(".ui-title").show();     
    }
});
```

Comment: would something like this work??? $(document).on('focus', 'Table', function() { $.mobile.activePage.find("div[data-role='footer']").hide(); })